# Set VSO build/release number as Azure application setting

Tags: azure

I'm using Visual Studio Online as a build server. How can I set the build & release numbers as an Application Setting in the Azure deploy step of a release definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're able to get these numbers (which you should using available variables from https://www.visualstudio.com/pl-pl/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/variables#default-variables), you can update web app's settings by using **Azure PowerShell** task with a script (or two) like:

```
param (
  [string]$WebAppName,
  [string]$SettingName,
  [string]$SettingValue
)

$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name $WebAppName
$appSettingsList = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings

$hashList = @{}
foreach ($kvp in $appSettingsList) {
  $hashList[$kvp.Name] = $kvp.Value
}

$hashList[$SettingName] = $SettingValue

Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $webApp.ResourceGroup -Name $WebAppName -AppSettings $hashList
```

where SettingName and SettingValue are name and value of app setting you want to add/modify.

So script arguments may look like `-WebAppName your-web-app -SettingName ReleaseNumber -SettingValue $(Release.ReleaseId)`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The release vars I was looking for were `Build.BuildNumber` and `Release.ReleaseName`. I made slight changes as well because I knew the names of the settings I wanted to change, so I baked them into the script instead of as a param.